# What operations contribute to Spark Task Deserialization time?

Tags: apache-spark

I have some jobs where tasks are dominated by task deserialization time.  The tasks themselves complete in about 10 seconds after 3 minutes of task deserialization.

What are the exact boundaries of this metric?  What resource limitations most often contribute to long deserialization times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick buzz into the source code on master (https://github.com/kayousterhout/spark-1/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala#L179)

It's essentially this:

```
    val (taskFiles, taskJars, taskBytes) = Task.deserializeWithDependencies(serializedTask)
    updateDependencies(taskFiles, taskJars)
    task = ser.deserialize[Task[Any]](taskBytes, Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader)

    // If this task has been killed before we deserialized it, let's quit now. Otherwise,
    // continue executing the task.
    if (killed) {
      // Throw an exception rather than returning, because returning within a try{} block
      // causes a NonLocalReturnControl exception to be thrown. The NonLocalReturnControl
      // exception will be caught by the catch block, leading to an incorrect ExceptionFailure
      // for the task.
      throw new TaskKilledException
    }

    attemptedTask = Some(task)
    logDebug("Task " + taskId + "'s epoch is " + task.epoch)
    env.mapOutputTracker.updateEpoch(task.epoch)
```

From this line `(taskFiles, taskJars, taskBytes)` I suspect that each task is deserializing the JARs;  in my case I have a 136 MB fat JAR that isn't helping.

Comment: I'm not sure that you are right. looking here: https://github.com/kayousterhout/spark-1/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala#L371 , the `jars` contain only the name and the timestamp, so it shouldn't take so much time to desirialze